# How to make the contact us submit button send emails to my email?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, contact-form

I'm very new, trying to use the contact us form in my website that will send the contact us form queries to my email. I'm using a template and I have no idea how to send those form queries to my email.

How to make this contact us form working in my static website not server side language because I want to make it work with html and javascript like the person enters the Name, Email and Message in the form and then when clicked on the submit button then I receive the person data to my email account

These are the codes.

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-xs-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Contact Us</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Use ths form to contact us.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email physics.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 text-xs-center">
                                <div id="success"></div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript code for the form**

```
   $(function() 
{ $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            });
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});
    $('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

Comment: Your `contact_me.php`-file should include some PHP-code to send the e-mail

Comment: Sending s-mails directly from client code on a web page is a bad idea, if even possible. You usually want to call your server back to do that stuff. Wherever you've taken this sample from, you might want study it more thoroughly. To give  you a hint, this code calls a PHP script "././mail/contact_me.php" on the server, which, I suppose, implements e-mail sending. I would suggest to study at this script in you   the sample you've got.

Comment: follow this tutorial for core php mail: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form and this for PHP mailer plugin https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/send-mailer-using-phpmailer-jquery-ajax/233285

Comment: can someone show me the php code then writing the code in php in jsfiddle? Where to upload that php file in my server?

Answer (score -1):

All the form values can be accessed in your php code with `$_POST`

```
<?php
$recipient = 'your@email.com';
//construct your email text here
$message = 'Name: '.$_POST['name'].'<br/>Email: '.$_POST['email'].'Phone: '.$_POST['phone'].'<br/>Message: '.$_POST['message'];
mail($recipient, 'MAIL SUBJECT', $message);
?>
```

The `mail()` does the task of sending the mail. You can read more about it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

You can upload the php script in the main root of the public folder of the server. However that means you'll change the url of the ajax call to just 'contact_me.php' provided the page using the javascript is in the same folder with the php script

Comment: This is a bad answer. First of all, it takes all data the script receives unchecked, which has a huge potential for issues such as e-mail header injection (so it will basically allow spammers to send mails to _anyone_), and secondly, it uses `mail()`, which is an absolute primitive tool and causes lots of issues as well (on the receiving end; those mails get classified as spam much easier). Using a library such as PHPMailer or SwiftMailer is highly recommended to avoid that.

Comment: I completely agree with you @CBroe, I was trying to simplify things and I ignored the safety aspect of it. I'll put that in mind anytime I need to answer another question